# A lot of errors,unable to fix .Please Help!

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% There are many different themes available for Beamer. A comprehensive
% list with examples is given here:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
% You can uncomment the themes below if you would like to use a different
% one:
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{boxes}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{LEoNIDS}

% A subtitle is optional and this may be deleted
\subtitle{A Low-Latency and
Energy-Efficient Network-Level
Intrusion Detection System}

\author{NIKOS TSIKOUDIS \inst{1} ANTONIS PAPADOGIANNAKIS \inst{2} \and EVANGELOS P. MARKATOS \inst{2}}
% - Give the names in the same order as the appear in the paper.
% - Use the \inst{?} command only if the authors have different
%   affiliation.

\institute[National Institute of Technology Kurukshetra] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}
 Brandeis University, Waltham, MA 02453, USA
  \and
  \inst{2}
  Institute of Computer Science,Foundation for Research and Technology-Hellas, Heraklion 700 13, Greece
  }
% - Use the \inst command only if there are several affiliations.
% - Keep it simple, no one is interested in your street address.

\date{IEEE Transaction on Emerging Topics in Computing \\ 26 Feburary 2016}
% - Either use conference name or its abbreviation.
% - Not really informative to the audience, more for people (including
%   yourself) who are reading the slides online

\subject{Cyber Security}
% This is only inserted into the PDF information catalog. Can be left
% out. 

% If you have a file called "university-logo-filename.xxx", where xxx
% is a graphic format that can be processed by latex or pdflatex,
% resp., then you can add a logo as follows:

% \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
% \logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

% Delete this, if you do not want the table of contents to pop up at
% the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

% Let's get started
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
  \section {Introduction}
  \section{Motivation}
    \subsection {Why Detection Latency Matters}
    \subsection{Why Power Consumption Matters }
  \section{Towards Power Proportional NIDS}
    \subsection{Experimental Environment}
    \subsection{Power Consumption}
    \subsection{Adapt to the Traffic Load}
  \section{Energy-Latency Tradeoff in NIDS}
   \subsection{Detection Latency}
   \subsection{Deconstructing Detection Latency}
   \subsection{Delay Analysis}
  \section{Solving the Energy-Latency Tradeoff}
   \subsection{Identify The Most Important Packets For Detection Latency}
   \subsection{Tolerating Evasion Attempts}
   \subsection{Time Sharing}
   \subsection{Space Sharing}
   \subsection{Delay Analysis With Priorities}
  \section{Implementation}
    \subsection{Time Sharing}
    \subsection{Space Sharing}
  \section{Experimental Evaluation}
    \subsection{Comparing Time and Space Sharing}
    \subsection{Comparing All Approaches}
   \section{Related Work}
   \section{Conclusions}
   \section{References}     
\end{frame}

% Section and subsections will appear in the presentation overview
% and table of contents.


%\begin{frame}{Blocks}
%\begin{block}{Block Title}
%You can also highlight sections of your presentation in a block, %with it's own title
%\end{block}
%\begin{theorem}
%There are separate environments for theorems, examples, definitions and proofs.
%\end{theorem}
%\begin{example}
%Here is an example of an example block.
%\end{example}
%\end{frame}

% Placing a * after \section means it will not show in the
% outline or table of contents.
\section*{Summary}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    The \alert{first main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    The \alert{second main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    Perhaps a \alert{third message}, but not more than that.
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Outlook
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Something you haven't solved.
    \item
      Something else you haven't solved.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}



% All of the following is optional and typically not needed. 
\appendix
\section<presentation>*{\appendixname}
\subsection<presentation>*{For Further Reading}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{For Further Reading}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \beamertemplatebookbibitems
  % Start with overview books.

  \bibitem{Author1990}
    A.~Author.
    \newblock {\em Handbook of Everything}.
    \newblock Some Press, 1990.


  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
  % Followed by interesting articles. Keep the list short. 

  \bibitem{Someone2000}
    S.~Someone.
    \newblock On this and that.
    \newblock {\em Journal of This and That}, 2(1):50--100,
    2000.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose. You can also have a look at [minimal working example (MWE) guidelines](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\section` and `\subsection` etc. should be placed *outside* frames, not inside.  Hence, move the `\end{frame}` of the frame containing `\tableofcontents` to before all those `\section` and `\subsection` macros, and your code will work. To make the ToC span multiple frames, use

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

Of course, it makes more sense to place the section headings at the corresponding place in the presentation, rather than bunched up at the start, like you have.

Comment: Thanks .It worked.One more help- I have a lot of sections & when I am trying to use framebreaks to break it into multiple pages but it's not working.

Comment: Here's the code:

Comment: \begin{frame}{allowframebreaks}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

Comment: \section{Energy-Latency Tradeoff in NIDS} 
   \subsection{Detection Latency}
   \subsection{Deconstructing Detection Latency}
   \subsection{Delay Analysis}
  \framebreak

Comment: @Er.ABCool You want `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]` (brackets, not braces), see code I added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for {}-> [].